# Tensorflow: FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized (using tf.data.Dataset API)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the `tf.data.Dataset` API in conjunction with `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor`.

My dataset was created like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'reviews': x}, y)))
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
data_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(tf.constant(data_vocab))
labels_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(tf.constant(labels_vocab))
```

Then I map a preprocessing function across my `dataset`:

```
def preprocess(x, y):
    # split on whitespace
    x['reviews'] = tf.string_split([x['reviews']])
    # turn into integers
    return data_table.lookup(x['reviews']), labels_table.lookup(y)
```

All good so far.  However, when I try to pass my dataset to my Keras model for training, I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized.
```

I googled around and people suggest that I need to include:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
```

But now I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized.
     [[Node: hash_table_Lookup = LookupTableFindV2[Tin=DT_STRING, Tout=DT_INT64](hash_table_lookup_placeholder, StringSplit:1, hash_table_lookup_placeholder_1)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_1 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,?], [?,20]], output_types=[DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator_1)]]
```

Any idea why my lookup table is *still* not initialized / how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi it's quiet weird maybe the following working example will help you:

```
x = ['this is aswesome', 'i dont like it', 'i love it', 'i hate it']
y = ['positive','negative','positive','negative']
data_vocab = list({word for sentence in x for word in sentence.split(' ')})
label_vocab = list(set(y))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({'reviews': x}, y))

data_table=tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(tf.constant(data_vocab))
labels_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(tf.constant(label_vocab))

def preprocess(x, y):
    # split on whitespace
    x['reviews'] = tf.string_split([x['reviews']])
    # turn into integers
    return data_table.lookup(x['reviews']), labels_table.lookup(y)

preprocessed = dataset.map(preprocess)

it = preprocessed.make_initializable_iterator()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(it.initializer)
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
```

If you call `sess.run(it.get_next())`you get `(SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]]), values=array([2, 7, 4]), dense_shape=array([1, 3])), 1)`

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Shouldn't I be able to just initialize the table with `sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())` and then pass my `dataset` to my Keras model?  The error occurs once I call `model.fit(...)` . Also, I shouldn't have to initialize my dataset to get a Keras model to train on it, I don't think

Comment: Normally you can just pass your dataset, I am wondering how you handle your sessions ? Are you sure that you're using the same session ?

Comment: I just run `sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer()) `, build my Keras model, and call `.fit` on the dataset

Comment: Can you try to add this line `tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)` before fitting your model.